# HTML 5 Video buffering and jQuery $( document ).ready()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

Whenever I want to show a loading screen on a web-page, I use jQuery's "$( document ).ready()" function to detect this, and set the body's CSS to visible once it has loaded. Easy.

However, I'm currently working on two websites that use background video. I'm using HTML5 video for this. I was just wondering how I should combine the two?

Basically, I want the loading screen to show until the video is ready to play, and then it autoplays. I guess just until it's buffered enough to start playing without stuttering. I don't want to wait for the whole video to load because it's a music video

Answer (score 1):

HTML5 media elements fire a lot of events. One of them is called "canplaythrough" and is what you seem to be looking for.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/canplaythrough

Comment: Hi Nico. I'm still struggling with this

Comment: You have a `<video>` element somewhere playing your background video. With `$('#ID_OF_YOUR_ELEMENT').on('canplaythrough', function (event) { alert('do something'); });` you can wait for the moment, the video thinks it is ready to play through.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a combination the HTML `buffered` property and `duration`. Both these properties will return a time value.Since the basic idea is to show the loading screen until the video is ready to play i.e. it is fully buffered, you could try something like this:

```
if(video.buffered.end(0) == video.duration) { 
  // do your thing
}
```

So if the length of buffered video is equal to the duration of the video, it will mean the video is ready to play.

Comment: Thanks. Just to clarify, does this mean I won't have to wait for the whole file to load before 'doing my thing', just for it to buffer enough that it can start playing with little risk of stuttering?

Comment: @mike_freegan I guess you'll have to wait for the entire video to buffer before executing the rest of your code using this logic. Otherwise you could try using `video.buffered.end(0) <= video.duration && video.buffered.end(0) != 0`, just to note however this is untested code.